# I am doing a tutorial to learn firebase and it uses an earlier version of firebase. What is the firebase 9 syntax for this code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the link to the part of the tutorial I am working with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWy9ylc3f9U&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jUPIes_B8vRjn1_GaplOPQ&index=15
Here is the code that I have from the tutorial. I have looked all over the internet to try and get this to work. The goal is to display a persons bio that they typed in when signing up to the site. I think the issue lies on the line db.collection('users').doc(user.uid.get().then(doc => {... but I'm not sure. Any help would be great. thanks!

```
`const setupUI = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // account info
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
      const html = `
        <div>Logged in as ${user.email}</div>
        <div>${doc.data().bio}</div>
      `;
      accountDetails.innerHTML = html;
    });
    // toggle user UI elements
    loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
    loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
  } else {
    // clear account info
    accountDetails.innerHTML = '';
    // toggle user elements
    loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
    loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
  }
};`
```

I've tried getdoc, getdocs, setdoc, and I am unable to get it to work. the best I can get is undefined.

Comment: Have a read of the [legacy to modern migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). The reason I suggest reading this is because you are going to come across a lot of outdated code samples and its best to build up the skills on how to rework any legacy code.

Comment: @samthecodingman That was very helpful and I was able to get it done. Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider answering your own question to help future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have doc and getDoc imported from firebase/firestore and put in the following code:

```
const loggedOutLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-out');
const loggedInLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-in');
const accountDetails = document.querySelector('.account-details');
const setupUI = async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      const html = `
        <div>Logged in as ${user.email}</div>
        <div>${docSnap.data().bio}</div>
      `;
      accountDetails.innerHTML = html;
      // toggle user UI elements
      loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
      loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
    } else {
      // clear account info
    accountDetails.innerHTML = '';
    // toggle user elements
    loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
    loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
    }
}};
```